# Rails cant start server serializers has_many error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, serialization

The error I am currently getting is:

```
`has_many': wrong number of arguments (given 5, expected 1..2) (ArgumentError)
```

It is referencing one of my serializers but everything seems to be correct what is happening here? It works on localhost just not production

```
class Api::V1::HomePageSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  has_many :banners, :daily_deals, :left_slider_products, :right_slider_products, :bottom_slider_products
  class Api::V1::BannerSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
    attributes :main_banner, :top_banner, :bottom_banner, :link
  end
  class Api::V1::DailyDealSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
    attributes :product_id, :title, :item_price, :discount_price, :pick_url, :pic_index, :image
  end
  class Api::V1::LeftSliderProductSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
    attributes :title, :product_id, :image, :scheduled_date_start, :scheduled_date_end, :item_price, :discount_price, :picture_url, :picture_index
  end
  class Api::V1::RightSliderProductSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
    attributes :title, :product_id, :image, :scheduled_date_start, :scheduled_date_end, :item_price, :discount_price, :picture_url, :picture_index
  end
  class Api::V1::BottomSliderProductSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
    attributes :title, :product_id, :image, :scheduled_date_start, :scheduled_date_end, :item_price, :discount_price, :picture_url, :picture_index
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to write associations one at a time,

```
has_many :banners
has_many :daily_deals
has_many :left_slider_products
has_many :right_slider_products
has_many :bottom_slider_products
```